# MySQL Dump waiting for table metadata lock

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a mysqldump along the lines of:

`mysqldump -u root -p db > C:\FileLocation`

However, when I run the command it never finishes. I therefore used: `SHOW PROCESSLIST`; to see what was going on. In the state of my dump query, the state reads: 'Waiting for table metadata lock'. There are only two other processes running on the database (besides the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command), both of which are sleeping.

I tried killing the other two processes and then doing the dump which worked for me. However, I'd like the dump to work regardless of whether the two processes working. Is there a way to go about that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Managed to figure it out in the end...

All I had to do was add: `--single-transaction=TRUE` to the start of my original query. IE:

`mysqldump --single-transaction=TRUE -u root -p db > C:\FileLocation`

Which allows the process to run without having to lock tables.